# How to install Caret package? While installing, I am getting this message

Tags: r, ggplot2, package, r-caret

```
library(caret)
```

> Loading required package: ggplot2 Error: package or namespace load
>   failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),
>   versionCheck = vI[[i]]):  there is no package called ‘gtable’ Error:
>   package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded

Comment: First `install.packages("caret")`, and `install.packages("ggplot2")`, then `library(caret)`

Comment: Also, make sure that you have no other R instances open with those packages loaded when you do package installs.

Comment: i have tried this but along with this it said to download following package also ....lattice, lava so i think steps will be as you said above             
First install.packages("caret"), and install.packages("ggplot2"), install.packages("lattice"), install.packages("lava").. then library(ggplot2) then library(lattice) then library(lava)

Answer (score 8):

Try this...

```
install.packages('caret', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue (R 3.5 for Windows).

Just had to keep going installing the missing dependencies until everything installed (for me there were about 10 dependencies missing)

This even required changing to a different mirror when the files could not be found!

Hope this helps someone in future...

```
> install.packages('caret', dependencies = TRUE)
> library('caret')
Loading required package: ggplot2 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package called ‘gtable’ Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded
> install.packages('gtable', dependencies = TRUE)
> install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
> library('caret')
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘gower’
> install.packages('gower', dependencies = TRUE)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-cran-caret
```

Answer (score 1):

So what worked for me is a bit old school: after installing the caret package and getting that error, I did a quick search on my PC for caret (In my case; I went to ThisPC > RoseAdediran), deleted the caret folder, searched for `plyr` and deleted the folder as well. Went back to RStudio, restarted the session and tried this code again

```
install.packages('caret', dependencies=T)
library(caret)
```

Once you load the library, other imports would be loaded as well.

Comment: Old questions to common problems hardly become irrelevant :) We removed some parts of your answer that are not related to the problem at hand. The site [tour] explains how collaborative editing works here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

install.packages('caret', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue for another package, and the easiest way to fix it was as follows(in RStudio):

1. Close all open .rmd, .r and .rnw files.
2. On the right hand lower corner I pressed on Packages and then on update. I selected all packages that needed an update and updated them. (You might also need to restart R, which can be done via Ctrl + Shift + F10).

After this I had no problems.

Answer (score 1):

when attempting:
install.packages("caret")

I'm getting the following errors:

Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.mtu.edu/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.mtu.edu/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.mtu.edu/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.mtu.edu/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘~/Downloads/caret’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

(yes, I should upgrade)

Solved by installing from the Rstudio CRAN repo:

install.packages('caret', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')

Answer (score 0):

As Ian suggested, try installing the package mentioned in the error message. I had the same issue and the error was 'there is no package as Biobase'. So I searched on the web for Biobase, installed it, tried library(caret) and it asked for another package and I kept installing till library(caret) worked. In your case, it shows 'there is no package called ‘gtable’. So start with installing gtable and load caret and keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when updating to R 3.5, if you changed R versions using something like the `updater` function from the `installr` package, it has some problems copying the libraries between major releases (3.4 -> 3.5).

The solution that worked for me was installing manually all the previous libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote the command

> install.packages("caret")

on my rmd file and had problems with the installation. It was solved just by typing the same line in the console.

Comment: No one else differentiated between trying that command in the rmd file vs the console.  So this does not seem to have been covered in previous answers.

Answer (score -1):

just try this

```
install.packages(pkgs = "caret", 
             dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports"))
```